# Can't run telethon code for Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, telethon

I'm trying to run this following code in the Jupyter notebook but it's giving me the error: 
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'get_me'

But it runs fine on Visual Studio Code. Any idea why?

Here's the code:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, sync

api_id = ******
api_hash = '********************************'

client = TelegramClient('session_test', api_id, api_hash).start()

me = client.get_me()
print(me.stringify())
```

Comment: are you sure you are on the latest version ? also did you try the normal async way ?

Answer (score -1):

Replace me = client.get_me() with await client.start()

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, sync

api_id = ******
api_hash = '********************************'

client = TelegramClient('session_test', api_id, api_hash)

await client.start()
```

then you can use client.get_me()

Comment: it says 'await' outside function